# how to solve this recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

i have a problem with an exercise.
It's a recursive function .In the parameters I have a dict, a starting city and a list of clues.
I have to return a list with the secrets (last item in the list of lists).
start from the starting city, then follow the list of clues, then follow the repetition of the second city.

Dict:

```
 {('ROMA', 'la'): [['PARIGI', 'vendita'], ['CAIRO', 'furto'], ['MOSCA', 'mata']], ('PARIGI', 'bocca'): [['BERLINO', 'diamanti'], ['CANCUN', 'cannoni']], ('CAIRO', 'bocca'): [['MILANO', 'di']], ('MOSCA', 'bocca'): [['PECHINO', 'hari']], ('BERLINO', 'sollevò'): [['PECHINO', 'rubati']], ('CANCUN', 'sollevò'): [['ROMA', 'mercato']], ('MILANO', 'sollevò'): [['PARIGI', 'diamanti']], ('PECHINO', 'sollevò'): [['MILANO', 'ha']], ('PECHINO', 'dal'): [['ROMA', 'stanotte']], ('ROMA', 'dal'): [['MOSCA', 'nero']], ('PARIGI', 'dal'): [['CAIRO', 'a']], ('MILANO', 'dal'): [['PARIGI', 'sedotto']], ('ROMA', 'fiero'): [['PARIGI', 'ad']], ('MOSCA', 'fiero'): [['BERLINO', 'del']], ('CAIRO', 'fiero'): [['CANCUN', 'buckingham']], ('PARIGI', 'fiero'): [['PECHINO', 'ambasciatore']], ('PARIGI', 'pasto'): [['CANCUN', 'anversa']], ('BERLINO', 'pasto'): [['CANCUN', 'cairo']], ('CANCUN', 'pasto'): [['MILANO', 'palace']], ('PECHINO', 'pasto'): [['MILANO', 'zambia']]}
```

Clues:

```
['la', 'bocca', 'sollevò', 'dal', 'fiero', 'pasto']
```

Initial_city:

```
'ROMA'
```

My code:

```
secret = []
def getSecret(city_dict, initial_city, clues):
    if (len(clues) == 0):
        return secret
    for clue in clues:
        if (initial_city, clue) in city_dict:
            secret.append(city_dict[(initial_city, clue)][0][1])
            return getSecret(city_dict, city_dict[(initial_city, clues[0])][0][0], clues[1:])
```

My wrong output:

```
 ['vendita', 'diamanti', 'rubati', 'stanotte', 'ad', 'anversa']
```

It should be:

```
[['vendita', 'diamanti', 'rubati', 'stanotte', 'ad', 'anversa'],['vendita','cannoni','mercato','nero','del','cairo'],['furto','di', 'diamanti','a', 'buckingham','palace'],['mata','hari','ha','sedotto','ambasciatore','zambia']]
```

Some advice?

Comment: What is `city_dict`? Is that your list of lists (and not a dict)?

Comment: yes,it's a list of lists

Comment: In any case, based on the fact that the expected output needs to be a list of lists, and you only append a single element, that should tell you something is wrong with your approach

Comment: You have a `return` statement inside a for loop, so the loop will only ever iterate once.  Is that intentional?

Comment: sorry its 'a dictionary not a list of lists

Comment: What does " then follow the repetition of the second city." mean? Since your function only returns the first list `['vendita', 'diamanti', 'rubati', 'stanotte', 'ad', 'anversa']`, it looks like you successfully implemented the first part (start from the initial city, then follow the list of clues) but haven't implemented the second part (follow the repetition of the second city). But I have no idea what it means.